# Import and Export data from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I want to ask if there's a way to make the import and export tasks from SQL Server to Excel occur whatever the version of Office installed. I made a software and want to install it on client's PC so I don't want to change the connection string every time I find any version of Office.. I want the software to import and export from Excel 2007, 2010 or 2013

[Import and Export wizard from my SQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmQxP.png)

The image uploaded shows that SQL Server 2008 only supports Excel 2007, what do I do if SQL Server 2008 is installed on client PC which has Office 2013 installed?!

Comment: Excel 2007 file format is the same as 2010, 2013 and 2016, so you won't have problems with the version.

Comment: I know but the problem is when I browse to the Excel file and choose the Excel version i don't find anthing else Excel 2007 so I chose it and it shows error message that "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)"

Answer (score 0):

Office 2007 and 2007+ share the same data configuration setting you can use import and export on 2013 as well. If it is not working you may need to install the Runtime drivers.
Please follow the link for your reference: 
[Data Source (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189667.aspx)

Comment: I download it but still error message appears : ""The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)"

Comment: Right Click on Solution Explorer ==> GOTO: Add Reference ==> GOTO: .Net tab ==> Scroll Down for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excell Version (12.0.0.0) and click OK.